# How can I edit a GitHub secret by using GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github, devops, github-actions, dockerhub

I have a script that deploy my application in DockerHub and I want to start to create versions for it by using the Actions of GitHub. But for it I need to edit some environment variable like this:

```
env:
    version : ${{ secrets.VERSION }}

- name: Build Docker Image
    run: docker build -t $REPO:version -t $REPO:${GITHUB_SHA::8} .

run: version++
${{ secrets.VERSION }} = version
```

How can I edit a variable and store it in GitHub Secrets?

Comment: You can't, and there are healthier alternatives to do this

Comment: Can you tell me which alternatives are there? Pls

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. For Python, there is [python-semantic-release](https://github.com/relekang/python-semantic-release) github action. There are similar projects for other stacks, too